# Change font of Verbatim slide in Beamer

Tags: fonts, beamer, verbatim

I have several slides in a beamer presentation where i'm presenting some programming code. However, the font ends up being too large and isn't fully featured on the slide. How can I change the font on the verbatim on a beamer slide. Furthermore, is there a way to keep it left alligned, but move it closer to the center of the slide.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
\begin{verbatim}
> library(apsrtable)
> y = rnorm(100)
> x1 = rnorm(100)*3
> mod1 = lm(y ~ x1)

> y2 = rnorm(150)
> x1 = rnorm(150)*3
> mod2 = lm(y2 ~ x1)

> y3 = rnorm(130)
> x1 = rnorm(130)*3
> mod3 = lm(y3 ~ x1)

> apsrtable(mod1, mod2, mod3)
\end{verbatim}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to change it for all frames, write into the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\ttfamily\tiny}
\makeatother
```

However, package `listings` or `fancyvrb` allow more flexible verbatim modes